# Xamarin: Accessing values inside local functions

Tags: ios, xamarin, firebase-authentication

I'm working on integrating Firebase Auth into my app. I've had to set up an interface to use platform-specific code (iOS and Android) to create users. My interface method in iOS "CreateNewUser" calls the "Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser" method that creates a new user. How can I get the "userID" variable from within the local function be the return value for the greater "CreateNewUser" function?

```
  public string CreateNewUser(string email, string password)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hhhhh");
        string userId = "";

        Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password,(authResult, error) => {

            Console.WriteLine("idd is " + authResult.User.Uid);
            userId = authResult.User.Uid;

        });

        return userId;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use a `TaskCompletionSource` to get it to work.

```
public Task<string> CreateNewUser(string email, string password)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>(); 

    Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password,(authResult, error) => {

        Console.WriteLine("idd is " + authResult.User.Uid);
        tcs.SetResult(authResult.User.Uid);

    });

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

You can then just do `await CreateNewUser("bla","bla");`